# Writing to a .csv file with C++?

Tags: c++, csv

TL;DR I am trying to take a stream of data and make it write to a .csv file. Everything is worked out except the writing part, which I think is simply due to me not referencing the .csv file correctly. But I'm a newbie to this stuff, and can't figure out how to correctly reference it, so I need help.

Hello, and a big thank you in advance to anyone that can help me out with this! Some advance info, my IDE is Xcode, using C++, and I'm using the Myo armband from Thalmic Labs as a device to collect data. There is a [program](https://market.myo.com/app/55009793e4b02e27fd3abe79/myo-data-capture) (link for those interested enough to look at it) that is supposed to stream the EMG, accelerometer, gyroscope, and orientation values into a .csv file. I am so close to getting the app to work, but my lack of programming experience has finally caught up to me, and I am stuck on something rather simple. I know that the app can stream the data, as I have been able to make it print the EMG values in the debugging area. I can also get the app to open a .csv file, using this code:

```
const char *path= "/Users/username/folder/filename";
std::ofstream file(path);
std::string data("data to write to file");
file << data;
```

But no data ends up being streamed/printed into that file after I end the program. The only thing that I can think might be causing this is that the print function is not correctly referencing this file pathway. I would assume that to be a straightforward thing, but like I said, I am inexperienced, and do not know exactly how to address this. I am not sure what other information is necessary, so I'll just provide everything that I imagine might be helpful.

This is the function structure that is *supposed to* open the files: (Note: The app is intended to open the file in the same directory as itself)

```
void openFiles() {
    time_t timestamp = std::time(0);

    // Open file for EMG log
    if (emgFile.is_open())
    {
        emgFile.close();
    }
    std::ostringstream emgFileString;
    emgFileString << "emg-" << timestamp << ".csv";
    emgFile.open(emgFileString.str(), std::ios::out);
    emgFile << "timestamp,emg1,emg2,emg3,emg4,emg5,emg6,emg7,emg8" << std::endl;
```

This is the helper to print accelerometer and gyroscope data (There doesn't appear to be anything like this to print EMG data, but I know it does, so... Watevs):

```
void printVector(std::ofstream &path, uint64_t timestamp, const myo::Vector3< float > &vector)
{
    path << timestamp
    << ',' << vector.x()
    << ',' << vector.y()
    << ',' << vector.z()
    << std::endl;
}
```

And this is the function structure that utilizes the helper:

```
void onAccelerometerData(myo::Myo *myo, uint64_t timestamp, const myo::Vector3< float > &accel)
{

    printVector(accelerometerFile, timestamp, accel);

}
```

I spoke with a staff member at Thalmic Labs (the guy who made the app actually) and he said it sounded like, unless the app was just totally broken, I was potentially just having problems with the permissions on my computer. There are multiple users on this computer, so that may very well be the case, though I certainly hope not, and I'd still like to try and figure it out one more time before throwing in the towel. Again, thanks to anyone who can be of assistance! :)

Comment: Have you checked if the file [`is_open()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/is_open)?

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: You're using a relative path to open the file, with directories. If your working directory does not contain those directories, instead of simply creating them the file open operation will fail. Use an absolute path, just a file, or use a filesystem manipulation system (like an implementation of the filesystem TS or boost.filesystem) to generate the appropriate directories. It's always a good idea to check that the file open succeeded, though. Can you verify that you do or do not have the correct files in your working directory, or that it works when you just use a file?

Comment: I know for certain that the file open is working, because after I have ended the program, I can check the file, and the "date modified" time is the same time that I began running the app.

Comment: "Note: The app is intended to open the file in the same directory as itself" - that will only be the case if the actual *working directory* of the process is the folder where the app resides. if the app is executed from a shell as `./appname` *and* there is no subsequent activity in the application that changes the cwd, only *then* can you have confidence the intention you state is probably true. Also, I find it odd the global you're preparing for writing is `emgFile`, yet the actual file you're using in `printVector` is `accelerometerFile`. *Real* code is what's for dinner.

Answer (score 0):

My imagination is failing me.  Have you tried writing to or reading from ostringstream or istringstream objects?  That might be informative.  Here's a line that's correct:

```
std::ofstream  outputFile( strOutputFilename.c_str(), std::ios::app );
```

Note that C++ doesn't have any native support for streaming .csv code, though, you may have to do those conversions yourself. :(  Things may work better if you replace the "/"'s by (doubled) "//" 's ...

Comment: I hadn't tried that yet. The filenames that were accompanying the ostringstream in every function were different, so I sorta assumed that everything with only one filename wouldn't work. When I am back at my computer with the project on it, I'll try it first thing. As for the "/" vs "//", "//"ing has no effect, I did try that one. I wasn't aware that c++ doesn't have natural streaming support, because I've run this app on a PC before with no problems. After I end the app, the .csv file is supposed to then open up with all the data in it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant you might have to replace single / 's with double \\ 's.  Just because Windows says it'll read the 1st type of path doesn't mean it will...  Second, there are paths an app needs administrative privileges to read from..  As far as C++ not supporting .csv files "by itself", I mean that if you don't have a serialization layer that does the required conversions for you, you'll have to do that yourself.

Comment: I'm not on Windows, its OSX. I've gotten this app to run on Windows before without any problem, but right now I don't have access to a non-Mac device, so I'm stuck with this. Anyways, unfortunately I found a bigger flaw with this app, rendering the entire thing useless, so now I've got to go learn how to implement this same concept using Bluetooth. Yay.... :(